# Javascript passes object by reference only one hop, but not two?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

Javascript passes an object to my function by reference, but it seems the receiving fn can't pass it on to a second function.

I have a button on my main HTML document like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Epoch"
    onclick='epoch(cl2Status, opts2)' />
</form>
```

It passes two objects to a function "epoch" which looks like this:

```
function epoch (clStatus, opts) {
   startClockAt (clStatus.cid, opts, 2, 23, 11, 20);
   stopClock (clStatus.cid);
   clStatus.clockStopped = true;
}
```

The two objects passed to "epoch" are just collections of simple data items. To illustrate their structure, here is how one was created (and the other is very similar):

```
cl2Status = {
     clid:          2,
     cid:           'clockCanvas2',
     testing:       false,
     nightTime:     false,
     clockStopped:  false,
     faceHidden:    false
};
```

Function "epoch" passes those two objects to a second function that uses data items from the objects and must also change the value of one of the items before passing the object on yet again.

By inserting alert statements at various places, I can see that although "epoch" can read the data, my second function can't. I have read that although ordinary scalar variables only get passed by value, javascript passes objects by reference. (At least for all practical purposes, even if that description is not quite accurate.) If they can be passed to one function, why can't it pass them on to another?

Is there a way to do it so that the object can be passed around over several hops?

Comment: Please provide a **complete, executable sample** demonstrating this problem. You're only showing part of the code, and a vague description about the rest. That doesn't help, let the code speak for itself. Note that we don't need to see all *your* code, just as much code as is necessary to reproduce this phenomenon by itself.

Comment: You're saying two things - one they aren't passed by reference, the other is you're saying it can't be passed to a second function at all. What is the actual behavior your observing that is leading to your conclusions? Whether something is passed by reference or by value, any function can read it. Passing by reference has to do with when you make changes to it are they on a local copy, or the original copy.

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you are not passing the entire object to the second function, you are only passing the 'cid' property of the object. Try passing the entire 'clStatus' object to the second function.

Comment: only the 2nd object (opts) needs to be passed on entirely.

Comment: Please provide an example of your  startClockAt method then so we can see what is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .cid properties from your function calls:

```
 function epoch (clStatus, opts) {
   startClockAt (clStatus, opts, 2, 23, 11, 20); //just pass in the object clStatus
   stopClock (clStatus);
   clStatus.clockStopped = true;
}
```

Comment: Whoops! Problem solved: (This is embarrassing) it was a typing error! Seems I can't detect the difference between opts and Opts. (It looks much clearer in this font.)